# C++ calling parent function only works when using a pointer

Tags: c++, inheritance

Of these two programs the second one works but the first one does not compile. How is that possible? The only difference is that in version two bar is a pointer and in version one it isnt.

Version one: (does not compile)

```
#include <iostream>


class Foo{

    public:
        void print(){
            std::cout << "asdasd" << std::endl;
        }

};

class Bar : public Foo{


};
int main(){
    Bar bar();
    bar.print();
}
```

And the second version:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo{

    public:
        void print(){
            std::cout << "asdasd" << std::endl;
        }

};

class Bar : public Foo{


};
int main(){
    Bar* bar = new Bar();
    bar->print();
}
```

Comment: Another most vexing parse question...

Comment: Why the downvotes?  Very fair question and very well-researched.  Not exactly easy to google for this situation.

Comment: That being said you need to post your error message.  And ideally google it and see what tends to cause it.

Comment: Most vexing parse strikes again.

Comment: Some weird language settings in windows 8 cause my error messages to be in broken swedish mixed with english and strange symbols, I thought about posting it but it makes no sense.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Bar bar();
```

is a declaration of a function.

```
Bar bar;
```

is your friend.